# Airdrop function executing but balances not updating

Tags: erc-20, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp, airdrop

I created the following code for token generation and airdrop. The token generation is working. I am able to execute the Drop() function (and got confirmations of contract execution) but the token balances are not getting updated . Your help is highly appreciated

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// '0Fucks' token contract
//
// Deployed to : 0xe4A96B299064aD3168dd6D503be747A59eb39c61 
// Symbol      : BCKE
// Name        : Test Token
// Total supply: 100000000
// Decimals    : 18
//
// Enjoy.
//
// (c) by Moritz Neto with BokkyPooBah / Bok Consulting Pty Ltd Au 2017. The MIT Licence.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe maths
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call
//
// Borrowed from MiniMeToken
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Owned contract
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract Owned {
    address public owner;
    address public newOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

    function Owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }
    function acceptOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = address(0);
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and assisted
// token transfers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract BCKEToken is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function BCKEToken() public {
        symbol = "BCKE";
        name = "Test TokenE";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
        balances[0xe4A96B299064aD3168dd6D503be747A59eb39c61] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), 0xe4A96B299064aD3168dd6D503be747A59eb39c61, _totalSupply);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account tokenOwner
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to to account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer tokens from the from account to the to account
    // 
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the from account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account. The spender contract function
    // receiveApproval(...) is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Don't accept ETH
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function () public payable {
        revert();
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
    }
}

contract Airdrop {
  function drop(address addr, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    BCKEToken token = BCKEToken(addr);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I am calling the function in etherwallet
https://pasteboard.co/HqS8kfT.png

Comment: If you provide the transactions corresponding to the airdrop it would be easier to diagnose what's happening.

Comment: Here is the transaction https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x3318ab8dcb4ed75cabe950594d0d54a2d35b436e4aec79bd95da59e6e7d0d541

Comment: The error in that transaction is you didn't specify a recipient (the array recipients is empty), also the values array has a single element (both arrays have to be of the same length).

Comment: This is how I am calling the function https://pasteboard.co/HqS8kfT.png . I am using etherwallet. Let me know what I am missing

Comment: @Ismael...  any thoughts ? Trying to get this working for last week.  Really appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry, it is better if you edit your question and the screenshot, also add etherwallet as tag.

Comment: Please publish and verify the code of the contract here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x4323383a842fcb0f7c9232b508ea6b6532bbfd83 and https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x5302b05a960791f64d1426bc4e1d839821777b66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note there are many flaws in the Airdrop contract:

- the drop function should have the onlyOwner
- modifier token's contract
  address should not be passed as a parameter but it should be fixed
- `0xe4A96B299064aD3168dd6D503be747A59eb39c61` is the address of the
  owner not the address of the contract
- and so on...

So I suggest a very deep review if you want to put that code into main net.

Said that, the issue you refer is caused by wrong balance.

Doing this:

```
token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
```

you are trying to move tokens owned by the Airdrop contract (`0x4323383a842fcb0f7c9232B508eA6b6532bbFd83`) to those recipients. This is because `msg.sender` in the transfer function of the token contract assumes the Airdrop contract's address and not the original sender of the transaction (`tx.origin`). In your case all tokens belongs to `0xe4A96B299064aD3168dd6D503be747A59eb39c61` and not to the Airdrop contract. You can change the transfer function to `transferFrom` and use `allowance` to allow the Airdrop to move tokens owned by other accounts.

Comment: @darkknight Answered